# In Trello, I want to upload files larger than 10 MB

Tags: trello

I am going to using Trello to collaborate with school personnel on a study. I need to upload video and audio recording files that will be larger than the 10 MB limit. Anyway to accommodate us? Can we purchase extra space?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible to purchase more space right now.

However, they just released (August 22, 2012) Google Drive integration, see their blog post [Introducing Google Drive Integration](http://blog.trello.com/introducing-google-drive-integration/) on the Trello blog. It allows you to attach files from your Google Drive account. The upload limit is limited only by Google Drive's limit, which is 10GB according to [Google Docs size limits](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603).